# One token causes segmentation fault and the other token doesn't

Tags: c

I have a function that reads filenames from directories. I want to extract these names, put them in an array for later use, fullname, namepart and extension part (3 different arrays). My function is able to write fullname and namepart NOT the extensions. Can anybody help me, here is my code extract; token 1 can be copied into the array, but copying token 2 results in segmentation fault;

```
while((entry=readdir(dirp2))!=NULL) 
            {
                strcpy(t_filename,entry->d_name);
                exception1=strcmp(entry->d_name,".");
                exception2=strcmp(entry->d_name,"..");
                exception3=strcmp(entry->d_name,".svn");
                if((exception1!=0)&&(exception2!=0)&&(exception3!=0))
                {
                    num_files++;
                    extension[num_files-1]=(char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));
                    strcpy(t_string, entry->d_name);
                    token1=strtok(t_string,".");
                    token2=strtok(NULL,".");
                    strcpy(extension[num_files-1],token1);       
                }

            }
```

Comment: What will happen when `token2==NULL` ? It's a no-brainer to check its value.

Comment: Also, a filename may contain any number of periods. You are just guessing the length with `malloc(20*sizeof(char));`

Comment: regarding this line: 'extension[num_files-1]=(char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char));'  1)  in C, do not cast the returned value from malloc  2)  sizeof(char) is always 1, so remove that phrase.  3)  always check (!=NULL) the returned value from malloc to assure the operation was successful

Comment: need to check (!= NULL) the returned value from each call to strtok() to assure a token was successfully found

Comment: Many thanks, your suggestions improved the results, more especially checking (!=NULL). Seg Faults disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

if you, on a *inx platform, open a terminal and enter 'ls -al'  you will see that the '.' and '..' directory lines have no text name, therefore, no extension.

so the posted code is trying to skip those entries.

The posted code is also trying to skip any directory name that ends in 'svn'

the token1 is everything before the first '.' (or whole string if no '.' in name.

the token2 is everything between the first '.' and the end of the string. (or NULL if no '.' in string.

the code is only keeping in the array, token1

Token1 can be NULL of the file name starts with a '.'

to acquire a pointer to an 'extension' string.

start at the end of the string and work back toward the front of the string, looking for a '.'

if a '.' is not found or found in the first char position, then there is no extension so the pointer to the extension should be NULL